# How to recursively copy a row every 15 rows in Microsoft Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have an Excel sheet with 10,000 rows. Say a personal budget and expense tracker. It tracks my income and expenses on a weekly basis. I am paid every 15 days. So i want to recursively add a static row in my excel sheet for every 10 or 15 rows which looks something like this below

I want the income row to be repeatedly pasted (say) every 10 rows automatically. I don't want to do it manually.

Can this be automated?

[image]

Comment: Loop through the rows with `Step 15`? https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/step-keyword.html

Comment: You say you want the income row repeated, but what about the rest (that seems repeating as well). If you want those repeated, what's the logic behind the counter of expenses? It counts from 1 to 8, then back to 5 & 6. If you don't want them to be part of the repetition, why share them in your example?

Comment: whre is the code you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, try the next code. I played with a virtual range built using an an array created on the fly:

```
Sub CopyRowAtConstVal()
 Const rW As Long = 10   'The interval of the copying the range
 Const frstR As Long = 2 'row to be copied
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, arr, rng

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A column
 
 'build an array for the set interval:
 arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & Int(lastR / (rW + 1)) & ")*" & rW + 1 & ")")
 
 Set rng = sh.Range("A" & Join(arr, ",A")) 'the range obtained from the above array (cells in A:A)
 sh.rows(frstR).Copy rng.Offset(frstR)     'copy the row to be copied (`frstR`) in the discontinuous entire row range...
End Sub
```

The above solution is a little fancy... It has a limitation of the maximum 255 characters of the discontinuous range address `("A" & Join(arr, ",A")`, about 590 rows, but it can be solved testing its length (`Len`) and if the limitation has bee exceeded, create a `Union` range using a dictionary:

```
Sub CopyRangeAtConstVal()
 Const rW As Long = 10   'The interval of the copied range
 Const frstR As Long = 2 'row to be copied
 Dim sh As Worksheet, lastR As Long, rngUR As Range, arr, rng As Range, k As Long

 Set sh = ActiveSheet 'use here the sheet you need
 lastR = sh.Range("A" & sh.rows.count).End(xlUp).row 'last row in A:A column
 Set rngUR = sh.UsedRange 'set the used range to avoid copying the whole row (only columns in used range)
 
 'build an array for the set interval:
 arr = Evaluate("TRANSPOSE(ROW(1:" & Int(lastR / (rW + 1)) & ")*" & rW + 1 & ")")
 If Len("A" & Join(arr, ",A")) <= 255 Then 'if concatenated array is less than 255 digits:
        Set rng = sh.Range("A" & Join(arr, ",A")).Offset(frstR)
 Else
        arr = Split("A" & Join(arr, ",A"), ",") 'create another array
        Dim i As Long, strArr As String, cellsNo As Long, dict As Object
        Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        For i = 0 To UBound(arr)
               strArr = strArr & "," & arr(i) 'create a string by concatenation of the array elements (comma sep)
               If Len(strArr) >= 250 Then    'if the string length is near 255 (maximum for such a range)
                   If Not dict.Exists(1) Then
                       dict.Add 1, sh.Range(Mid(strArr, 2)).Offset(frstR) 'create first virtual string
                   Else
                      Set dict(1) = Union(dict(1), sh.Range(Mid(strArr, 2)).Offset(frstR)) ' create a Union range
                       cellsNo = sh.Range(Mid(strArr, 2)).cells.count    'determine the last number of array elements guiding to
                   End If                                                                               'a string of a length less than 255 characters
                   strArr = ""                                   'renitializate the string
               End If
               If UBound(arr) - i < cellsNo Then 'if reach the last array elements which still create a string of accepted length
                   Set dict(1) = Union(dict(1), sh.Range(Mid(strArr, 2)).Offset(frstR)) 'add the existing to the dictionary
                   strArr = ""                                  'renitializate the string
                   For k = i To UBound(arr)
                       strArr = strArr & "," & arr(k) 'create the string from the last array elements
                   Next k
                   'add it to the union range and exit the loop:
                   Set dict(1) = Union(dict(1), sh.Range(Mid(strArr, 2)).Offset(frstR)): Exit For
               End If
        Next i
        Set rng = dict(1)
 End If

 'copy the used range of row to be copied (2) in the discontinuous entire row range...
 Intersect(sh.rows(frstR), rngUR).Copy Intersect(rng, rngUR.EntireColumn)
 
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

The above code processes 5000 rows in less than a second... It does not copy all the row, anymore. It copies only existing columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a starter for you:

```
Sub createsheet()
    Dim wk As Long, r As Long, e As Long
    Dim wsh As Worksheet
    
    Set wsh = ActiveSheet
    r = 1
    e = 1
    
    For wk = 1 To 52
    
        wsh.Cells(r, 1).Value = "Week" & wk
        
        wsh.Cells(r + 1, 1).Value = "Starting Balance"
        
        If wk = 1 Then
            wsh.Cells(r + 1, 2).Value = 0
        Else
            wsh.Cells(r + 1, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C"
        End If
        
        wsh.Cells(r + 2, 1).Value = "Income"
        wsh.Cells(r + 2, 2).Value = 1000 ' remove if to be manually input
        
        wsh.Cells(r + 3, 1).Value = "Expense " & e
        
        wsh.Cells(r + 4, 1).Value = "Expense " & e + 1
        
        e = e + 2
        
        wsh.Cells(r + 5, 1).Value = "Ending Balance"
        wsh.Cells(r + 5, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R[-4]C:R[-1]C)"
        r = r + 6
        
    Next
    
End Sub
```

Run this on a new worksheet and add some conditional formatting to produce the colouring your require.